# Magento issue of phtml file being called twice

Tags: crud, php, magento

I am creating a new module in Magento (simple CRUD Application)  , and the phtml file is called multiple times (twice) . Following is my code in layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <businesshours_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="businesshours/businesshours" name="businesshours" template="businesshours/businesshours.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </businesshours_index_index>
</layout>
```

This all are the method in my block class :-

```
<?php

class Techmentation_Businesshours_Block_Businesshours extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()  
    {       
        parent::__construct(); 
        $branches = Mage::getModel('businesshours/businesshours')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($branches);   
    }  

    public function getPostActionUrl()
    {       
        return $this->helper('businesshours')->getBusinesshoursPostUrl(); 
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getBusinesshours()     
    { 
        if (!$this->hasData('businesshours')) {
            $this->setData('businesshours', Mage::registry('businesshours'));
        }
        return $this->getData('businesshours');
    }

}
```

Why the content of phtml file is repeated twice ? How can I fix the issue ?

Comment: It's likely that either your block is declared as an output block (`output="toHtml") *and* a child block, or it is a child of two blocks. What does your block class look like?

Comment: Thank you , i think i need make changes either in construct or preparelayout or both of them

Comment: Nothing in your block class will cause it to render twice. You likely have an issue with layout directives.

Comment: I deleted the module and created it again, the issue is resolved but I still don't have an idea of the cause.

Comment: @benmarks you were totally right, output="toHtml" causes that.